# Terraform import : ignore specific resource from public module

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I trying to import the state of a (private ) s3 bucket which was created via the console. Im using the [`public s3 module`](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws/latest). I was able to create a module block and import the state of the bucket. However `terraform plan` also tries to create a `aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block` . How do I ignore or stop terraform from creating that specific resource from the module ?

```
main.tf


locals {
  region = "dev"
}

module "s3_bucket" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws"

  bucket = "my-${region}-bucket"
  acl    = "private"

  block_public_acls = true
  block_public_policy = true

  lifecycle_rule = [
    {
      id      = "weekly_expiration_rule"
      enabled = true
      expiration = {
        days = 7
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Import command for bucket - `terraform import module.s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket.this my-dev-bucket`

Meanwhile when I try importing the public access block resource I run into the error ` Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object, even when I have the settings configured on the bucket.

Comment: Your source code is not clear, you should update it (add version, provider, tf version, syntax ${local.region}, why region is dev? ...)

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the source code more carefully , specifically [this](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket/blob/940de5cbfff5688f57de5924dcd6748908e7c97d/main.tf#L426) section

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "this" {
  count = var.create_bucket && var.attach_public_policy ? 1 : 0
```

setting `attach_public_policy` to false got me what I needed

Comment: There is **count** in the source module, how can you import without index [0]?

Answer (score 1):

You should run terraform plan to see the real output and read the source code in github ([resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this"](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket/blob/master/main.tf#L5)). You can see **count** at line 6.

```
  # module.s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket.this[0] will be created   
  ...
  # module.s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.this[0] will be created   
  ...
```

You can import with these commands:

```
t import module.s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket.this[0] my-test-bucket-823567823576023
t import module.s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.this[0] my-test-bucket-823567823576023
```

My test main.tf, after I import it, `t plan` show `0 to add`

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13.1"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.69"
    }
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = ">= 2.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-southeast-1"
}

module "s3_bucket" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws"

  bucket = "my-test-bucket-823567823576023"
  acl    = "private"
}
```